# Sprites display with black in place of transparency

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to get this port of Descent 2 up and running on iOS:

https://github.com/devint1/Descent2-Mobile

I've got it compiling and running, but sprites are rendering with transparent areas as opaque black, when rendering with Open GL|ES.  The software rendering build option is completely broken, unfortunately.

I'd like to have a crack at fixing this and contributing the changes back, but despite being a very experienced iOS developer, Open GL|ES (and 3D game development) is completely unfamiliar. Seems like a good opportunity to learn something, if I can work out the correct jump-off point for investigations.

Where should I start looking and what should I be searching for, as an initial starting point for investigations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black is the default "error color" for OpenGL ES textures which fail at run-time for some reason, so are the sprites in a data format your device understands?